# Why is my shrink size so small for my SSD?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 and I need to shrink size in my SSD but shrink size looks so small. I don't know why it is like that. Why can it be like that?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LuQK.png]

Answer (score 1):

The text you shows indicate that the disk needs de-fragmentation, before you are able to shrink it.

Boot into windows and run disk defrag, and then try to shrink it again in disk management.

Comment: How can I do disk de-fragmentation?

Comment: @Atakan that's a Windows question, not about Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, I'll search it

Comment: @SorenA  Don't defrag a SSD.

Comment: @heynnema I was just defraging my SSD but I have cancelled it .I hope there won't be an effect to SSD.

Comment: @Atakan It's normally not a good idea to abort a defrag. It won't damage your SSD, but it may leave some files corrupt.

Comment: @heynnema hmm so there is no problem but what can I do to shrink size ?Is there any way to do it?